# Error in my makefile, flags are not treated appropriately. What can be the reason?

Tags: c, makefile

I have some issues with my makefile.
I have the following source codes: main.c cache.c cache.h
When I run make it is what I get...

```
  make
    gcc −ansi −pedantic −Wall −m32 -c main.c
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '−ansi'
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '−pedantic'
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '−Wall'
    clang: error: no such file or directory: '−m32'
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

And here is my makefile:

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS = −ansi −pedantic −Wall −m32
all:    c-sim
c-sim:  main.o cache.o
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -o c-sim main.o cache.o
main.o: main.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c main.c
cache.o: cache.c
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c cache.c

clean:
    rm -f c-sim
    rm -f *.o
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like your `gcc` isn't really `gcc`.  The error message indicates that it is in fact `clang`.

Comment: Because the error message begins with `clang:`

Answer (score 4):

Don't write scripts with a word-processor.

The problem is that options start with a simple <kbd>-</kbd>. However, you've managed to enter typographical dashes. (Compare them with the <kbd>-</kbd> in `-c`. Your <kbd>–</kbd> are slightly longer. Look closely.)

This might be because you incorrectly typed `--` instead of `-`. Gcc (and clang) allow but don't require long options (-pedantic and -ansi) to be specified with two dashes; that is the usual way of writing long options in other programs. Many word processors "correct" double dashes to an en-dash.

If you delete the en-dashes and replace them with simple single dashes, all will be well.

Answer (score -2):

The Cause of the Problem is that you are not using GCC Compiler but using Clang compiler. In Clang flags are provided as :

```
/W0 /Wall
```

but GCC flags are provided as

```
-Wall -g
```

Thus you have change the flags according to Clang.

Comment: clang is very compatible with gcc; it accepts options in the same format.